# Stripe PaymentIntent Card how to implement?

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement payments on stripe with PaymentIntent API.
My problem is that I don't find where/how to feed the card details (number, exp_year, exp_month, cvc) for the PaymentIntent.

Here's my code https://github.com/rever96/example-stripe-paymentIntent that create the PaymentIntent, and than confirm it. The confirm change the status to `succeded`. So that makes me think: "Wow, it's working!" But what about card details?

Thats the server code interested:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');

app.post("/createPayment", (req, res) => {
    console.log('i\'m trying to create a paymentIntent');
    (async () => {
        paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: 1099,
            currency: 'eur',
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
        }).then(paymentIntentResponse => {
            console.log("paymentIntent created");
            res.send(paymentIntentResponse)
        });
    })();
});

app.post("/confirmPayment", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    (async () => {
        paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(req.body.id, { payment_method: 'pm_card_visa' })
            .then(paymentIntentResponse => {
                console.log("paymentIntent confirmed");
                res.send(paymentIntentResponse)
            });
    })();
});
```

and that's the client code interested:

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/createPayment', {}).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('back from server!');
      console.log(res);
      this.paymentIntentID = res['id'];
      this.paymentIntentClientSecret = res['client_secret'];
    });
  }

  submitPaymentData() {
    this.collectCardDetails();
    console.log('confirm payment');
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/confirmPayment', { id: this.paymentIntentID }).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('back from server!');
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow of PaymentIntents generally goes:

1. Create PaymentIntent on the server
2. Pass client secret to frontend
3. Use Stripe Elements to collect card info
4. Use Stripe.js `handleCardPayment` to process the payment

You've done step 1, you need to complete the rest:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart#passing-to-client

Comment: Can you explain me how to do step 3? I read the docs, but cardElement is not explained

Comment: Since you're using Angular you might want to check out angular-stripe: https://github.com/kareniel/angularjs-stripe-elements

Comment: Here's the official docs on how to use Elements: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart

Comment: I still can't create a cardElement to feed handleCardPayment. Any more help?

Comment: You'd use Stripe.js to create the Stripe Element: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#elements-create

Comment: yes, but there is no way to import Stripe on front-end. I followed some online guide about declare var on file.d.ts, I tried with the docs suggestion https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#including-stripejs, but Stripe is not importable as she has no exported member named Stripe, even the constructor

Comment: upvote my question pls... I have too many questions without upvote and I can't question again..... thats sad